# How can I get the system process id of a running external command in Julia

Tags: operating-system, julia

Problem: 
I want to know the system process ID of a buggy external program invoked as a command from within a julia worker process.  Some of these external tool calls will result in a memory leak by that external program.

I would like to monitor the memory consumption of these system calls so that I can kill them if they pass a memory threshold instead of waiting for all system memory to be consumed and some sort of arbitrary memory allocation error to hit things running on the system.

I am looking for something like a nonblocking:

```
pid = @async run( `my_external_program` )
```

where pid would be the system process id for my_external_program

Comment: Looks like this could fit well into the future (not yet written, unfortunately) documentation on shell scripting and piping (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/julia-lang/topic-requests/555)

Answer (score 1):

Cheat.

```
#### In (executable) file "sleep_inner_wrapper"

#!/bin/bash
sleep 20                       # the actual command you want to run
echo -e "Finished sleeping\n"  # the event you want to detect on exit
```

```
### In (executable) file "sleep_outer_wrapper"

#!/bin/bash
./sleep_inner_wrapper &
jobs -p > mypid                # bingo
```

Your julia session if you don't kill the process:

```
julia> @async( run( `./sleep_outer_wrapper`))
Task (waiting) @0x00007f97a6303850

julia> pid = parse(Int64, chomp(readline(open("mypid","r"))))
10944

                          ... twenty seconds later ...

julia> Finished sleeping
```

Your julia session if you decide to kill the process:

```
julia> @async( run( `./sleep_outer_wrapper`))
Task (waiting) @0x00007f97a63036c0

julia> pid = parse(Int64, chomp(readline(open("mypid","r"))))
10930

julia> run(Cmd(ByteString["kill";"-9";"$pid"]))
```

Comment: PS. I never said anything about it not being ugly.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this in an OS agnostic fashing from within Julia itself.  This is easy to do in most other languages but tough to track down in Julia.  To get past this problem in my current situation, I too cheated by calling a perl wrapper script "[timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout)" which manages the descendent PIDs for you and lets you impose a memory or time limit at the time you spawn the command.

Comment: Hm, if you really wanted an OS agnostic way, the only way I see that happening at the moment is via a `ccall`

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can spawn a process asynchronously and grab a handle with `spawn`, e.g.

```
process = spawn(`sleep 10`)
```

this returns a `Process` object. Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to get the pid from this right now, but it should be possible. The `process.handle` field is a pointer to the underlying [libuv process struct](https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/processes.html). You could get that out by converting the struct to a Julia object, or alternatively you could write a small C function in Julia's source code to get it, e.g.

```
int jl_get_proc_pid (uv_process *proc) { return proc.pid }
# In Julia
pid(process::Process) = ccall(:jl_get_proc_pid, (Ptr{Void},), Int, process.handle)
```

This might be a nice opportunity to make a patch to Julia, although it would be nice if someone told me I was wrong and there's an easier way that I've overlooked :)

Comment: In particular, I would open an issue requesting this feature: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported simply via `getpid(::Base.Process)`: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Libc.getpid